# Capacitor for reducing voltage drops

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, batteries, lipo, gsm

I use gsm module, which makes current bursts up to 2Amps (maybe slightly more). That causes voltage drops about 0.5V on my power supply (I use lipo battery), and than device hangs up or starts glitching.

Now I use two 470uF, and smaller ceramic 22uF, 10uF, 1uF and 100uF tantalum caps. But they aren't enough.

Is it possible that my ground tracing is so bad that 470uF ones are enough but don't work? I put them quite close to  module input.

I decided to use a bigger one (3300uF, 6-10V) to try fix that problem.

However, do I have to use some special schematic to connect it? I mean that it will be like short circuit until get charged.

Thanks!

Comment: I will try another battery. I used a no-name 1000 mAh battery  from aliexpress so far, and I think that it's the main source of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I designed in the past quite a few boards with a GSM module on board. The boards were powered at 13.8 Volt.

I mainly used: Siemens TC35 and Gemalto BGS2 and others.

A FAE engineer at Siemens, back in 1999 told me: "Power supply is crucial for RF modems. If the voltage supply is not stable, the module refuses to transmit in order not to transmit unwanted harmonics".

In the first generation of boards I had one LM2596 DC/DC converter at 5 Volt for both the module and the micro controller. Back then, the maximum voltage for the phone was 6 Volt.

In the second generation of boards I had two LM317 DCYR linear regulators able to deliver 1.5 A. The first regulator was at 4.2 Volt for the GSM module and the second at 3.3 Volt for the micro controller. I had a 6-layer board and used one internale plane to dissipate heat. After all, my boards made 1 phone call at a month. The maximum temperature I saw during phone calls was 65 Celsius degrees. Linear regulator are GREAT.

I've never had problems since 1999.

GSM modems are certified by manufacturers at the power supply voltage of 3.8 V.

If the power supply voltage is not stable during TDMA bursts the module automatically turns-off due to voltage sags.

---

To answer your question:

I assume here that your board is done and you can't add a second regulator.

Raise up the power supply voltage of the GSM module to 3.8 V or 4.2 V.

Use 1 or 2 Schottky diodes to generate 3 V for your microcontroller.

See what happens.

Comment: My device is a wearable, and mainly powered by lipo battery (4.2-3.7V).

Comment: Wearable means small product. The PCB traces can't be the source of your problem. A capacitor between 3300 uF and 4700 uF is what GSM manufacturers suggest.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, its quite small, but, do I have to use some special charging protection  schematic? Or 3300uF isn't so big? BTW, where did you read this recommendations?

Comment: Charging is tricky for your board. When charging the battery the voltage goes up to 4.3 Volt and that may burn the microcontroller. Use a dedicated IC that disconnects the rest of the board while charging the battery. I've been designing GSM boards since 1998 and I read datasheets. Take a look at page 11 here: https://developer.gemalto.com/sites/default/files/wm_an_26_pwr_supply_v06.pdf

Comment: Oh,  no, excuse me, I meant charging of capacitor, not battery. I use special charging controller for battery.

Comment: You don't need nothing for charging capacitors. DC/DC converter have soft-start so don't worry if the total capacitance is big.